# Handling html array and javascript

Tags: javascript

I’ve been trying to make this work for a week now and migraine is a luxury compared to what my head feels right now,I want to make a simple checking using a check box array and its content may vary because its dependent on a table.

I read a lot of articles and some of them are very helpful, so i came up
with my script below.

```
function mybox() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.mycurrentform.mycheck.length; i++) {
        if (document.mycurrentform.mycheck[i].checked == true) {
            var result =mycheck[i].length;
            alert(result);  
        }
        else if (document.mycurrentform.mycheck[i].checked == false) {
            alert("No button checked!");
        }
    }
}

<form name="mycurrentform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox[]" value="valuefromtable">Click Me
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="mybox()">
</form>
```

My first aim is to find if there are checkboxes ticked and alert message shows.
the second I hope to count how many were ticked and alert message show. unfortunately
for my first aim it takes 3 tries to click the OK button before exiting. 
my second aim gives me an error message "error description: mycheck is not defined". 
I admit, I am lost and need a fresh set of eyes and hopefully direct me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's code missing, but you are using mycheck[i] where you could mean mycheckbox[i].